# PHP not working to create links

Tags: php, hyperlink, indexing, connector, building

I have this website **www.amse.com.br**

For some reason, every link on the website is not working, and I know where the problem is, but don't know why.

The index.php script handles the false URLs and brings information to the web page from the data base:

```
<?php
require_once("api/connector.class.inc");

$url_cod = (isset($_REQUEST['cod'])) ? $_REQUEST['cod'] : '';
$url_nm_secao = explode('/', $url_cod);

$url_id = Connector::getAllName("tab_url", "id_tabela", "nm_url='" . $url_nm_secao[count($url_nm_secao)-1] . "'");
$url_tabela = Connector::getAllName("tab_url", "nm_tabela", "nm_url='" . $url_nm_secao[count($url_nm_secao)-1] . "'");


if($url_tabela == "tab_produto"){
  $_REQUEST["codigo"] = $url_id;
  include_once "detalhe-produto.php";
}else if($url_tabela == "tab_subcategoria"){
  $_REQUEST["subcategoria"] = $url_id;
  include_once "lista-produto.php";
}else if($url_tabela == "tab_categoria"){
  $_REQUEST["categoria"] = $url_id;
  include_once "lista-produto.php";
}else if($url_tabela == "tab_grupo"){
  $_REQUEST["grupo"] = $url_id;
  include_once "lista-produto.php";
}else if($url_tabela == "tab_conteudo"){
  $_REQUEST["codigo"] = $url_id;
  include_once "detalhe.php";
}else{

  if(isset($url_nm_secao[0]) && $url_nm_secao[0] == '' || $url_nm_secao[0] == 'index.php'){
    include_once "home.php";
  }elseif($url_nm_secao[0] != ''){
    $paginas = array('contato', 'carrinho', 'cadastro', 'pagamento', 'logout', 'salvar-pedido', 'endereco-de-entrega', 'retorno', 'obrigado', 'meus-pedidos', 'salvar-orcamento');

    if(isset($url_nm_secao[0]) && in_array($url_nm_secao[0], $paginas)){

      include_once $url_nm_secao[0].".php";

    }else if($url_nm_secao[0] == "finalizar-compra"){
      $_REQUEST["compra"] = 1;
      include_once "cadastro.php";
    }       
    else if($url_nm_secao[0] == "busca"){
      include_once "lista-produto.php";
    }
    else if($url_nm_secao[0] == "locacao"){
      include_once "lista-locacao.php";
    }       

}else{
  include_once "home.php";
}
  } ?>
```

For example, `www.amse.com.br/contato` should bring up this page `www.amse.com.br/contato.php`

This should happen with every link on the website, but i'm getting `404`.

If you need any more information,

please leave on the comments!

Comment: Dont you mean "finalizar-compra" will bring up "contato.php" that is what you have above if I translated it right.  Ok, I see it is in the array. hmm.

Comment: finalizar-compra should bring cadastro.php, not contato.php. But every link is not working, there is some serious thing going on with this code...

Comment: It could certainly be structured better.  Personally I would use a Switch statement for this, or a router library.

Comment: this $url_nm_secao[count($url_nm_secao)-1] could be just end( $url_nm_secao ); for example

Comment: Yes, I know. This code is not mine though, it's from a client. But do you have any clue why it is not working at all?

Comment: Wait, never mind on that. lol it's hard to read.  What is the value of $url_tabela and $url_id for the url "www.amse.com.br/contato"

Comment: it should show www.amse.com.br/contato.php

Comment: I'll get the values on the data base, just a sec.

Comment: I can't find the value. Where exactly should I search?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63827/discussion-between-lucas-vallim-da-costa-and-artisiticphoenix).

Answer (score 1):

Your web server (Apache, etc) may not be configured to handle this type of clean URL.

By default a web server will look for a file with a matching name underneath its DocumentRoot, however your file is named `contato.php`, not `contato`.  This means Apache is potentially looking for a file named `contato` and not finding it, thus returning an HTTP 404 response.

If you are using Apache, a rewrite rule like this may be what you need

```
RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)([/a-zA-Z0-9]*)?$ /index.php?cod=$1$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

This will take everything after the initial `/` in the URL and pass it to your program in the `cod` variable, making it available in `$_REQUESt['cod']` above.  With this I imagine your index.php will work as expected.

Comment: yes, but that is exactly the problem. This index.php should handle this, and transform the links so the server will understand.

Comment: Generally the PHP code that powers websites is accessed on some server via a web server, not directly.  So performing this kind of clean URL handling entirely on the PHP-side (in some kind of index.php file, like you have here) without any kind of configuration to the web server may not be possible.  At least this is generally the case with Apache.

Comment: I agree most likely it is an .htaccess issue or lack of it. The title of creating links, made me think the links were not being generated properly.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help but I cleaned it up some for you this was what I was saying with using a switch

```
switch($url_tabela){
    case "tab_produto":
        $_REQUEST["codigo"] = $url_id;
        include_once "detalhe-produto.php";
    break;
    case "tab_subcategoria":
        $_REQUEST["subcategoria"] = $url_id;
        include_once "lista-produto.php";
    break;
    case "tab_categoria":
        $_REQUEST["categoria"] = $url_id;
        include_once "lista-produto.php";
    break;
    case "tab_grupo":
        $_REQUEST["grupo"] = $url_id;
        include_once "lista-produto.php";
    break;
    case "tab_conteudo":
        $_REQUEST["codigo"] = $url_id;
        include_once "detalhe.php";
    break;
    default:
        if( !isset( $url_nm_secao[0] ) ){
            $url_nm_secao[0] = '';
        }

        switch ( $url_nm_secao[0] ){
            case "finalizar-compra":
                $_REQUEST["compra"] = 1;
                include_once "cadastro.php";
            break;
            case "busca":
                include_once "lista-produto.php";
            break;
            case "locacao":
                include_once "lista-locacao.php";
            break;
            default:
            case 'index.php':
                include_once "home.php";
            break;
        }
    break;
 }
```

As you can see it's much easier to read, I haven't tested this but it should be fairly close to what you have.

Php documentation for Switch Case

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: Thanks! it's much easier like this. After we fix the problem i'll update it.

Comment: Sure no problem, I added a link to the php documentation on it.  It a better fit for this structure, and will be easier to add more routing on later then a if then setup.